# Crash shows Visual studio option. But not showing dont send message

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, crash

When I get any crash in my pc, I used to get don't send dialog box. But recently it is always showing some dialogbox, and it is asking to debug in visual studio. I dont want this dialog option. How can I remove this option.

Could any one knows information about this.
Thanks & regards,
Haranadh

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the "Just In Time Debugging" feature of Visual Studio.  You can disable this by deleting the following reg keys

To disable this feature follow the instructions at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(VS.80).aspx

Namely go Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Just In Time.  Uncheck both check boxes

Feature link: [Just In Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(VS.80).aspx)